# How do I call an array for Searchbar for Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do I get the correct viewcontroller after selecting a tableview cell can you please help me I think there is a problem with my index

```
import UIKit
var NamesC =  [ "one", "two"]

var IndexC = 0
class ComputerVC: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!

    var data = [ "one", "two"]

    var filteredData = [String]()

    var inSearchMode = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TableView.delegate = self
        TableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if inSearchMode {

            return filteredData.count
        }

        return data.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? DataCellC {

            let text: String!

            if inSearchMode {

                text = filteredData[indexPath.row]

            } else {

                text = data[indexPath.row]
            }

            cell.congigureCell(text: text)

            return cell

        } else {

            return UITableViewCell()
        }

    }
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {

            inSearchMode = false

            view.endEditing(true)

            TableView.reloadData()

        } else {

            inSearchMode = true

            filteredData = data.filter({$0.contains(searchBar.text!)})

            TableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        IndexC = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't specified the actual problem you are facing. I'm assuming that you are not getting the right value while you are showing the filtered data. If that is the case, keep in mind that you have to use `inSearchMode` in your `didSelectRow` or `prepareForSegue`(if you have any) appropriately. Just like you do in the rest of your code

Comment: The problem that I’m facing is I select so after searching for something I get the correct search content but when I select cell I don’t get the correct value which is the The view controller for the cell How do I correct this please help how do i use inSearchMode in didSelectRow

Comment: What is your requirement ?

Comment: what do you mean by requirement?

Comment: i want to get the correct view controller after searching  and selecting a cell

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
 {
     var text = ""

    if inSearchMode {

        text = filteredData[indexPath.row]

        let correctIndex = data.index(of:filteredData[indexPath.row])

        print("selected value is : \(correctIndex)")


    } else {

        text = data[indexPath.row]
    }


    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: text)
 }
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if let secondController = segue.destination as? SecondController {
         secondController.sendedValue =  sender as! String
     }
 }

 class secondController:UIViewController
 {
   var sendedValue:String?
 }
```

Comment: what do you want to send

Comment: I have a global array with names and descriptions
Inside the class I have an array of the names
And then I have the search code
I I can search just fine I get the correct result in the table view controller but when I select cell and go to the other three controller I get the wrong The content for the first cell in the index please help

Comment: please help me it is my graduation project:(

Comment: you want to get the index of the data array that appears in filterData ???

Comment: it did not work :( i added more information maybe you see where is the problem please help

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here:

`Name.text = NamesC[IndexC]`

Your array is filtered, your indexC is the one you used in the filtered array.

You can define a filtered array `FNamesC`, and update this array when you search in your search bar and in your viewController

`Name.text = FNamesC[IndexC]`

I don't know why you want a global array though.

Comment: i am using an global array to pass data

Comment: please help  i need to fix this issue